# How to skip lines in a text file if ID number is duplicated?

Tags: c#, file, csv, tabs

I have few criteria such as pick only records from to day, and also if a record contains the letters 'CA',
Now I would like to add a criteria before these two where I skip any record that is duplicated based on the ID numbers.

here is my code

```
    private void btn_convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((textBox1.Text == "" )&& (textBox2.Text == ""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please specify input and output");
        }

       StringBuilder csvFile = new StringBuilder();
       string temp = "";      
       // string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Program\Desktop\test.txt");         
       string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
       foreach (string line in file)
        {
            //here I want to add an if condition where only write the unique records based on ID number

          if ((line.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))) && (line.Contains("\tAU\t"))){ 
          if (line.Contains("\t"))
                 {
                temp = line.Replace("\t", ",");

                csvFile.Append(temp + "\r\n");

                continue;
                 }
            csvFile.Append(line + "\r\n");
                }
        }

    //File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Program\Desktop\test.csv", csvFile.ToString());
       File.WriteAllText((textBox2.Text + "\\test.csv"), csvFile.ToString());
       MessageBox.Show("CSV file successfully created at the following location :\n" + textBox2.Text);
    }
```

Comment: No sure why people are closing as too localized, you can ignore the code and input/output entirely and the question is still answerable, and applies to other people in the same situation (and it's a common situation, so there will be other people).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I assume you want to completely exclude records that appears multiple times, as opposed to keep just their first occurrence?

```
file = file.Where(line => line.Contains("\t"))
           .GroupBy(line => line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf('\t')))
           .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
           .Select(g => g.First())
           .ToArray();
```

Comment: You don't want to remove all records that are duplicated, just remove all but one line when they're duplicates, effectively a `Distinct` (you'd need to use `DistinctBy` or a custom comparer since he's not comparing every propery).

Comment: The OP's example appears to request the opposite. But you're right on the second point; I need to compare just the first part.

Comment: you're right.  Given that, you do need to adjust the `GroupBy` to `line => getIDFromLine(line)`  also need to change the select to `g.Single`

Comment: Original poster states he wants to remove the duplicates, and his example specifically shows he wants to completely remove all records with non-unique IDs, not keep the first record and omit the rest as he is currently doing.

Comment: @StarPilot Which is what this answer is doing with the `Where` clause, unless your comment was directed at me, in which case I've already acknowledged that mistake.

Comment: @Servy, I was commenting in reply to you. When I first commented, your acknowledgement wasn't posted/visible at that time. No worries.

Comment: @StarPilot You should use the @ reply if you're not replying to the poster you're commenting under.

Comment: This will NOT properly handle a CSV file.  CSV files are often comma (not TAB) separated and is in this case, and they can have QUOTED COLUMNS that embed separator characters.

Comment: @EricJ.: "I have a function that takes a tab delimited file […]". The OP is not parsing CSVs.

Comment: @Douglas: Hmmm... I guess that would imply no embedded delimiters.  Objection withdrawn.

Comment: This would not preform well on a large file, if at all.

Comment: @Douglas: How does this perform with a large number of records in the source file?

Comment: Performance would depend on the underlying implementation of `GroupBy`, which I assume is a hash-table, but I'll check.

Comment: @EricJ. Since you're addressing performance, what other implementations would use use that would perform better?  Given the requirements, you need to get all of the IDs before you know if any of them are good, unless you have a way of going back and removing a previously provided value when you find a duplicate.  You could possibly do two passes, one to get all IDs and find non-duplicates, and a second to get the data for those good rows.  It will take less memory, but do a lot more IO and so take longer.  Pointing out performance concerns doesn't mean much unless you propose an alternative.

Comment: @Servy: I was about to raise the same point. The only way of avoiding storing the entire file in memory is by reading it twice.

Comment: @Douglas See [edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby.aspx) for a basic implementation of GroupBy by Jon Skeet

Comment: @Servy: You can read only the IDs into memory, store them e.g. in a hash set.  No need to read the entire file, and you can add IDs to the hash set as you go.

Comment: @Servy: I was looking at the decompiled source. The crux of the logic appears to be in `Lookup<TKey,TElement>.GetGrouping`, which is hash-based.

Comment: @EricJ. Then you need a way of going back and removing whatever entry/record of a line when you find a duplicate for it.  You could possibly reduce the memory footprint a bit (depending on rate of duplicates) but it would have little, or a negative, impact on performance, and a rather sharp increase in code complexity.  I'd first see if the size of the file is too large to fit into memory (or may become that large later) before addressing such concerns.

Comment: @Douglas Yep.  As I said, jon skeet's edulinq is a fantastic resource, and that's how he implemented it as well.  I had no doubts it would be a hash based structure under the hood (given that I've seen people with problems resulting from invalid `GetHashCode` implementations when using `GroupBy`.  It also takes an `IEqualityComparer` rather than a `Comparer`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I've implemented your code , it compiled fine but crashed when I executed, where Exactly should I put this ? thanks

Comment: Place it just after the `string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);` line. What do you mean by crashed? Did you get an exception? Assuming you're changing the aforementioned line to load a file from disk, how large is the file?

Comment: @Servy: Based on his example, he just wants the *first* line if there is an ID collision.  No need to go back and remove previous output.  Code complexity is minor, memory footprint depends on collision rate but is probably less than or equal to the LINQ solution.

Comment: @EricJ.: Are you looking at the lines in the example beneath "current output file" or "desired output file"?

Comment: @Douglas the file is very small, i get the following exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Parameter name: length | length cannot be less than zero

Comment: @EricJ. No, look at the same input/output.  He wants any lines that result in collisions to be excluded entirely, rather than taking the first of any duplicates, which is why your answer was wrong.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify a little bit more

Comment: @user1880431: I assume the error is being thrown because some of your lines do not contain any TAB character. Try the amended version.

Comment: @Douglas Indeed the first line is a header , Your code solved my problem. Please someone vote him up because I dont have enough reputation .. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
        string x = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\test.txt"))
            x = sr.ReadToEnd();

        var mynewlist = (from v in x.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         let items = v.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         where items.Count() == 5
                         select new
                         {
                             ID = int.Parse(items[0]),
                             FamilyN = items[1],
                             LastN = items[2],
                             Country = items[3],
                             Date = DateTime.ParseExact(items[4], "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                         }).GroupBy(X => X.ID).Where(X => X.Count() == 1).Select(X => X.First());//add any condition here

        //mynewlist is a strongly typed List
        string output = "";
        foreach (var item in mynewlist)
            output += item.ID + "," + item.FamilyN + "," + item.LastN + "," + item.Country + "," + item.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "\r\n";


        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.csv"))
            sw.Write(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is just quick and dirty and I can't test it at the moment, so I can't even guarantee it'll work as-is, but it should be close enough to show you a way you can do it.

```
private void btn_convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((textBox1.Text == "") && (textBox2.Text == ""))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please specify input and output");
    }

    StringBuilder csvFile = new StringBuilder();
    string temp = "";
    string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
    List<int> idList = new List<int>();
    foreach (string line in file)
    {
        string[] cols = line.Split('\t');
        if (cols.Length > 0)
        {
            int colId = -1;
            if (int.TryParse(cols[0], out colId))
            {
                if (idList.contains(colId))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                idList.Add(colId);
            }
        }

        if ((line.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))) && (line.Contains("\tAU\t")))
        {
            if (line.Contains("\t"))
            {
                temp = line.Replace("\t", ",");

                csvFile.Append(temp + "\r\n");

                continue;
            }
            csvFile.Append(line + "\r\n");
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllText((textBox2.Text + "\\test.csv"), csvFile.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("CSV file successfully created at the following location :\n" + textBox2.Text);
}
```